# IntelliJ Kotlin - MainKt run/debug configuration unavailable, cannot run project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, program-entry-point, run-configuration

I'm trying to run a basic Kotlin main file but the problem is I don't have any run/debug configurations available.

My main.kt file is under src>main and is a very simple Helloworld program. See below image.
When I enter Add Configuration>Kotlin and type MainKt in Main Class, I get Warning: Class MainKt not found. In previous projects MainKt has been the default and I haven't had to add a configuration manually. Has anyone else come across this issue?

[Image of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOqrp.png)

[Run/Debug Configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJMXk.png)

[Project Structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElAKf.png)

[If I hit Run(in toolbar)>Run you can see no available configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIajn.png)

EDIT: added Main module to source and MainKt class is now available in Add Run/Debug Configuration, but I get the error in below image, "Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainKt"

[Error: Cannot find MainKt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFCSq.png)

Comment: just click the run button next to the main function in the kotlin file?

Comment: There is no run button next to the function, but I know what you mean as it's been there in previous projects.

Comment: Seems there is no MainKt class. Please try to remove existing run configuration and create new one.

Comment: Hi, I've just started this project from new and there are no run configurations available to remove. I cannot find the MainKt.class. Should it always be there by default or does it depend on your project setup when you create it?

Comment: Please share your project example.

Answer (score 1):

The source for the class MainKt (main.kt) does not appear to be under your sources root (src/main/kotlin), it's one level up if I interpret the UI of intellij correctly. Try moving it into the kotlin/ directory.

Comment: See above edit: this seems to have helped but now I have another error.